# the use definitive of article

Tags: definite-article

should I use "the" before "teachers"? this is the title of an article and I am not sure whether to put it or not. I will appreciate your comments on the use of definitive articles in the bolded sections.

A phenomenological analysis of **the** Teachers’ Perceptions of Ethical Factors Affecting **the** Teacher-Student Relationships

Answer (score 1):

***A phenomenological analysis of a Teacher's Perceptions of Ethical Factors Affecting Teacher-Student Relationships*** if you do not name/know the name of the teacher that you are referring to.

or

A phenomenological analysis of a Group of Teachers Perceptions of Ethical Factors Affecting Teacher-Student Relationships. If you do not name/know the names of the teachers that you are referring to

---

***A phenomenological analysis of The Perceptions of Ethical Factors Affecting the Teacher-Student Relationship*** if you know the name of the teacher that you are referring to and you intend to name that teacher in your paper.

or

A phenomenological analysis of The study Group of Teachers Perceptions of Ethical Factors Affecting Teacher-Student Relationships. If you name/know the names of the teachers that you are referring to.

---

*A phenomenological analysis of the Teachers’ Perceptions of Ethical Factors Affecting the Teacher-Student Relationships* is not correct in any case.

Comment: DEear Brad, of course, I don't know the names and I think the best case is to remove the not to put "a" in your first instance which is incorrect because it is plural.

Comment: I stand corrected on the plural.

Comment: Answer corrected accordingly.